# enter value of input to the html, not the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input in my html file (attribute `id` is: `imgName`).

while the user enters some text to this input, it's inserted to the DOM.

I want it to be inserted to the html.

so I try to do this thing:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == "imgName") {
        // get the char and create text node
        var text = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        // insert it to the input
        e.target.appendChild(text);
    }
});
```

but it does nothing..

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done something wrong:

1. Your are listening for an input-event on your complete document, but your input will only be on your input-field. so you need: *$('#imgName').keydown...*
2. You are using jQuery... so, use it to do this stuff is easier.
3. Your condition is not needed.

try this:

```
$('body').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dwcf2/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can't append something to an input, it's a self closing element that has no content, and to get the proper result from `String.fromCharCode` you should be using the keypress event

```
$('#imgName').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    document.body.appendChild(text);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/abD2j/)